# How to define Spring security access

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here is my spring-security.xml file. I don't understand how can i define access attribute. There are "ROLE_USER" and "ROLE_ANONYMOUS" as default but how can i define my custom access attribute? For example "admin" value is returning from database and how can i change this access to set admin.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="admin" />
```

Above code is giving error.

```
    <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="" />
    <form-login login-page='/pages/login.xhtml' default-target-url="/**"
                authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout.xhtml" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password 
          from app_user where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.role from app_user u, role ur 
          where u.role = ur.uuid and u.username =?  " 

    />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some changes as below

1. `<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">`
2. `<intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml*" access="permitAll"/>`
3. `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />`

Currently I'm using `Spring MVC 3.2` and `Spring Security 3.1`